# angular.forEach with object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

Hi I'm a bit new to angularjs, checked out the doc, still don't get it.

For example in a function I call the function getElementChildAttr

```
vm.element[0].estimate_sentVolume = getElementChildAttr('estimate', 'volume');
```

vm.element is an array containing objects.

Here is the function

```
    function getElementChildAttr(parent,child){

         var res = 0;
         angular.forEach(vm.element[0].subelement, function (something) {
             res += something[parent][child];
         });

         return res;
     }
```

so this works, it will for the first element, but i have 2 objects element, and i wish that the angular.forEach works with both elements, that i can iterate with an index through it, i tried stuff, didn't work, help ? (changed some elements / functions names some privacy) Thanks !

Edit : I think @NTP has a good idea, it should be 2 foreach, one for subelement inside a element one

Comment: try          `angular.forEach(vm.element, function (something) {
             res += something.subelement[parent][child];`

Comment: use 2 foreach loops 1 for elements and 1 for subelements

Comment: Mawg, this didnt work, says "Cannot read property 'volume' of undefined"

Comment: @Max can u post sample `vm.element` data ?

Comment: Sure, you have vm.element that will be an array containing objects like this:  [{ id: 0, name: test, subelement: [{ name: test1 } { volume: 200}] } { id: 1, name: test, subelement: [{ name: test2 } { volume: 100}] }

Comment: { id: 1, name: test, subelement: [{ name: test2 } { volume: 100}] }  why your data is like this?

Comment: what are u assigning to this vm.element[0].estimate_sentVolume = getElementChildAttr('estimate', 'volume');

Answer (score 0):

Can you try in this way?

```
 function getElementChildAttr(parent,child){

         var res = 0;
         angular.forEach(vm.element[0].subelement, function (something) {
             res += (something[parent])[child];
         });

         return res;
     }
```

Comment: Does not work ^^ i mean it does exactly the same thing that my actual code does. The problem is that it will work for the first element but will return the exact same value for others elements (for exemple vm.element[1])